# Seaborn: How To Get All Fit Parameters from seaborn.distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, seaborn

I've seen multiple poorly phrased questions on this topic on this website; I thought I would post one that is clear. Suppose I'm plotting a distribution with seaborn:

```
comp1 = np.random.normal(0, 1, size=200)
comp2 = np.random.normal(10, 2, size=200)
values = pd.Series(np.concatenate([comp1, comp2]))

sns.distplot(values, bins=100, color='k')
```

In this particular example, the kernels used for the fit appear to be two gaussian curves. How can I

1) Obtain ALL the kernels used in this fit

2) Get ALL the parameters for EACH kernel

I've read somewhere that the fitting used in seaborn is equivalent to the fitting in scipy.stats. Can someone confirm if this is true? If it is true, is there a 'kernel fit' method in scipy.stats like there is in seaborn?

Cheers,
Luke

Comment: There is always exactly one kernel used in a 1D KDE. I don't see how this question is particularly clear asking about multiple non-existing kernels. Seaborn uses `statsmodels` fitting if available, else it will use `scipy.stats`. Is your question how to replicate what seaborn is showing?

Comment: Perhaps I'm using the term 'kernel' wrong. Wes McKinney refers to a kernel as a simpler distribution like a normal distribution on page 279 of his Data Analysis Textbook. He claims that a fit using two or more gaussians consists of a combination of 'kernels.' I presumed therefore that each normal distribution was itself a 'kernel.' I want to get the information/parameters used for ALL kernels used in a particular seaborn distribution.

Comment: I find that definition a bit strange. In any case, a kernel density estimate (as done by seaborn) does not fit any normal distributions. It chooses a kernel with an appropriate bandwidth and shows the respective resulting probability density. Now you do have some control over which kernel to use but that does not give you any information about a "fit" to the data.

Comment: So how could I extract the parameters about the particular probability density function? Or are you saying that it doesn't actually use a particular function when it does the fit?

Comment: A kde does not fit anything. So maybe you want to forget about kde and seaborn and ask about what you really want to know?

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I'm currently just reading about seaborn; I don't actually need it for any particular application at the moment. I think if I ever needed to fit data and get the fit parameters, I would use scipy then worry about the plotting later.

Comment: Yes, that is a useful approach.

Comment: @LukePolson: You can get the fit data (x and y coordinates of the thin line in your plot) if you wish. Let me know if you want that.